# How to get download data back after reinstall app which is uninstalled

Tags: android, download, scope, storage, android-11

I have font file download in android 11 Download Folder in app folder which is working, the issue is when i uninstall app and re-install,

I can't get pack previously downloaded font, is it possible? then help to resolve this is issue occur in only android 11 OS,

Thanks.

Comment: "download folder" or "app folder"? thats crucial the difference. afaik "app folder" (aka. scoped storage) is cleared out after uninistall, thats one of purposes of scoped storage - don't allow apps to leave own files taking up space. files in system "download folder" should stay

Comment: @snachmsm: Yes, but the file downloaded by the first installation of the app will be inaccessible to the second installation of the app. From Android security's standpoint, those are two separate apps, and one app does not have rights to access files from another app without user involvement (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`).

Comment: Let me clear , download font in default download directory Download -> App Folder -> Fonts - TestFont.ttf

Comment: After un-install app and re-install it can't get back this TestFont.ttf file

Comment: @CommonsWare i don't think so...because if it is correct then it should not work in my app too. I have whatsapp tools application, in that I am copying statuses and also copy/share/delete files(images, videos, stickers, database files, document files) from "Android/media/whats_folder". Also I'm copying files to "Pictures/MyAppFolder". After uninstalling my app and again installing all my old data can access.

Comment: Possibly downloading fonts is  at incorrect place. Should try it in "Documents" or "Android/media/app_package_name/AppFolder"

Comment: @pratikvekariya: `Pictures` is not `Downloads`, and the rules vary by location.

Comment: @CommonsWare you mean to say Pictures and Download folder have different rules?

Comment: @pratikvekariya: Correct (and I apologize -- I had a typo in my previous comment that I corrected shortly after submitting it). On Android 11+, apps do not have access to other apps' files in `Downloads/`. And, in the case of uninstall-and-reinstall, the second install is considered to be a separate app from the original install. [This blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/01/11/scoped-storage-stories-diabolical-details-downloads.html) goes into more detail, and while it refers to `MediaStore.Downloads`, filesystem access has the same limitations.

Comment: @CommonsWare got it, Thanks. So what about "Android/media/app_package_name" ? If I'm not wrong then I think we can store all types of files in this folder....Right? because whatsapp is doing same.

Comment: @pratikvekariya: I have not tried playing with those directories, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare okay, thanks.

Comment: @GauravMandlik you should try to download and read file from "Android/media/app_package_name". I think that will be work.

Comment: @pratikvekariya I have the same points which you wrote. Have you got any rigid answers to them?
I believe sooner this *"Android/media/app_package_name"* will also not work after 1-2 Android versions. Pls, confirm if you have any solutions to this.